# Elasticsearch cluster design for 390M documents / 710GB dataset

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a dataset of 390M documents (totaling 710GB). Each document can contain multiple paragraphs of text and a number of tags e.g.:

```
{
    body: "When you reach the end of your rope, tie a knot in it and hang on",
    author: "Franklin Roosevelt",
    authors_title: "President of the United States",
    type: "quote",
    year: 1870,
    location: "Washingon, DC, USA",
    authors_overview: "Franklin Delano Roosevelt, often referred to by his initials FDR, was an American politician who served as the 32nd president of the United States from 1933 until his death in 1945"
}
```

Queries are often performed on multiple fields and often have to search thru the entire dataset. 
The volume of searches is actually fairly low (<10 / sec) and writes mostly happen in bulk (every few weeks).

As a proof of concept I inserted the whole dataset into a single Elasticsearch node on a server with 32 cores, 128GB of RAM and a 1.5TB SSD. The JVM Heap size is set to 29Gb.

This setup works, but queries are slow (often taking 20-30s). Ideally I would like queries to be under 1 second.

What type of cluster would you suggest in order to accomplish this? (# nodes, # shards, hardware)

Thank you very much for the help!

edit:

**mappings**

```
properties: {
  authors_title: {
    type: "text",
    analyzer: "title_indexing_analyzer",
    search_analyzer: "title_search_analyzer",
  },
  body: {type: "text", analyzer: "default_analyzer"},
  author: {
    type: "text",
    analyzer: "default_analyzer"
  },
  authors_overview: {
    type: "text",
    analyzer: "default_analyzer"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried to increase JVM Heap?! See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tune-for-search-speed.html

Comment: I really don't think you need add another node. Your documents looks simple and your queries too. Try posting your mappings and queries here so we can try to optimize it

Comment: Also see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/preload-data-to-file-system-cache.html

Comment: @EliasSoares I can try to increase it further but from reading online it seems that I should increase it to at most ~30GB (or jump to 64Gb for a server with at least 128GB of ram)

Comment: @EliasSoares I just increased the JVM heap size to 29GB and it got somewhat faster. Tho some queries are still taking 20s.

Comment: Can you share one of those queries too? They may be optimizable too.

Comment: Since it's basically a readonly index you can use force merge with max_num_segments=1 in order to fully merge the index. This not recommended since it messes up the automatic merge policy, but if you do this automatically after the completion of your writes every few weeks you'll be fine. Moreover, you can increase or completely disable the refresh interval. Also, if you are using elastic as a service, automatic snapshots can be every 24 hours. As a last note, you can stop indexing (let them be saved, just not be searchable) any fields that you do not search or aggregate against.